# Why does Cypher query performance increase after recreation of neo4j DB?

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I use neo4j 3.5.13 community edition. My application periodically  makes a set of cypher-queries like this:

```
MERGE (unit:unitOfMeasureRegion{ name:"unit_1" })
MERGE (object:object { name: "obj_1" })
MERGE (object)-[:HAS_MEASUREMENT_UNITS]->(unit)
MERGE (object)-[:HAS_ROLE]->(role:someRole)
MERGE (object)<-[:PROVIDED_BY]-(value:SecAttributeValue)-[:IS_PART_OF]->(unit)
SET value.begin_of_time_region=datetime({somedate})
SET value.end_of_time_region=datetime({somedate})
RETURN value.begin_of_time_region, value.end_of_time_region, unit.name, object.name, id(value)
```

... and:

```
MATCH (unit)<-[:HAS_MEASUREMENT_UNITS]-(object:object { name: "object_1" }) 
WITH object, unit MATCH (object)<-[:PROVIDED_BY]-(value:SecondsAttributeValue)-[:IS_PART_OF]->(unit) 
WITH object, value, unit 
MATCH (object)-[:HAS_ROLE]->(role:someRole) 
RETURN value.begin_of_time_region, value.end_of_time_region, unit.name, id(value)
```

Also I created indexes:

```
Indexes
   ON :object(Name) ONLINE 
   ON :unitOfMeasureRegion(Name) ONLINE
```

I clean out database by `MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n` (There were about 70 000 nodes) and from that point some part of the queries start run very slow i.e. for some label `value:SecondsAttributeValue` they are OK but if I change it to another label e.g `value:MinuteAttributeValue` then queries slowdown.

I also set memory settings in `neo4j.conf` in accordance with the `neo4j memrec`.

As workaround I recreated neo4j database so the problem disappears (all queries run pretty fast ).

What can be a reason of this?